# ArrayList select coordinates, if there are less clients than coordinates, give each client a coordinate

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    Coordinate[] coords = {
        new Coordinate(3093, 3630), new Coordinate(3095, 3632), new Coordinate(3098, 3633),
        new Coordinate(3101, 3633), new Coordinate(3104, 3631), new Coordinate(3106, 3629), 
        new Coordinate(3107, 3627), new Coordinate(3108, 3624), new Coordinate(3109, 3620),
        new Coordinate(3108, 3617), new Coordinate(3106, 3614), new Coordinate(3102, 3613),
        new Coordinate(3099, 3613), new Coordinate(3097, 3613), new Coordinate(3093, 3614),
        new Coordinate(3090, 3617), new Coordinate(3087, 3619)
    };


    int random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
    Coordinate coord = coords[random];
    boolean found = false;

    if (insidePlayers.size() < coords.length) {
        if (spawnPoints.contains(coord)) {
            found = false;
        }
        while (!found) {
            random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
            coord = coords[random];
            if (!spawnPoints.contains(coord)) {
                player.spawnPointX = coords[random].getX();
                player.spawnPointY = coords[random].getY();
                spawnPoints.add(coord);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        player.spawnPointX = coords[random].getX();
        player.spawnPointX = coords[random].getY();
    }
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is, if there are more clients than available coordinates (spots), then give each player his own coordinate (So other clients can't have the same coords).

But unfortunately it doesn't work, sometimes clients are getting the same coordinates.
Why is it happening? what did I do wrong?

Coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinate {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

ArrayList:

```
public static ArrayList<Coordinate> spawnPoints = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

***So what's wrong there?***

Comment: Where's the loop to assign coordinates to more than one player? Also, what's `spawnPoints`? Some kind of `Set`?

Comment: spawnPoint saves the coord X/Y of the client for future uses, the loop is outside of this code, basically loops through all clients, and runs the method startGame(Client player), so each player goes through this code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `equals()` in your Coordinate class.

```
@override
public void equals(Object o){
if(o==null)
 return false;
if(!(o instanceof Coordinate)){
  return false;

Coordinate newO = (Coordinate) o;
if(this.x == newO.x && this.y == newO.y)
  return true

return false;
}
```

This is because [ArrayList#contains](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses [ArrayList#indexOf()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)  which is defined as:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
         if (o == null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                 if (elementData[i]==null)
                     return i;
         } else {
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                 if (o.equals(elementData[i])) /// <--- Uses .equals()
                     return i;
         }
         return -1;
     }
```

*Note*: While you are at it also override hashCode() as well. You don't really need it in your case but its a good practice and will help you if you use hash based data structures. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) will help.

Comment: Why though? I am not using equals() ? Kinda new to java by the way ^^

Comment: I've already tried doing the checking class-sided, and it didn't work, almost the same way as you, then tried this way I am using now and it didn't work aswell. What causing it to not work?

Comment: How are you populating `spawnPoints`?

Comment: @rocketboy - It's inside the inner `if`: a `Coordinate` is added when it is assigned to a `player`.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you have a set of spawn points, and you want to spawn players on these points but no two players can have the same spawnpoint. A simpler way of doing this would be to remove a coordinate from the list once it has been given to a player. Not sure how you feed in the clients (players), please elaborate on that if this solution doesn't help.

```
 Coordinate[] coords = {
    new Coordinate(3093, 3630), new Coordinate(3095, 3632), new Coordinate(3098, 3633),
    new Coordinate(3101, 3633), new Coordinate(3104, 3631), new Coordinate(3106, 3629), 
    new Coordinate(3107, 3627), new Coordinate(3108, 3624), new Coordinate(3109, 3620),
    new Coordinate(3108, 3617), new Coordinate(3106, 3614), new Coordinate(3102, 3613),
    new Coordinate(3099, 3613), new Coordinate(3097, 3613), new Coordinate(3093, 3614),
    new Coordinate(3090, 3617), new Coordinate(3087, 3619)
};

public static List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(coords));
public static final Random rnd = new java.util.Random();

if(!coordinates.isEmpty())
    int randomIndex = rnd.nextInt(coordinates.size());
    Coord randomCoord = coordinates.get(randomIndex);
    player.spawnPointX = randomCoord.getX();
    player.spawnPointY = randomCoord.getY();
    coordinates.remove(randomIndex);
else
    System.out.println("No more coordinates left to assign to player");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a combination of two factors: 1) you are allocating a new `coords` array each time into the method; and 2) your `Coordinate` class does not implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. The reason these cause a problem is that the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` inherited from `Object` are based on object identity, not equality of values. The result is that if, in one call, the `Coordinate` with values of (say) x=3093 and y=3630 is added to `spawnPoints`, on the next call, a new `Coordinate` object with the same x and y values will test as not contained in `spawnPoints`.

I think this can be fixed in one of two ways:

1. Declare the `coords` array to be a `static final` field instead of allocating a new array each time into the method. Then object identity will suffice for your logic.
2. Implement `Coordinate.equals(Object)` and `Coordinate.hashCode()` so that `Coordinate` objects with the same `x` and `y` field values test as equal and have the same hash code.

Even if the first approach fixes the problem, you should strongly consider implementing `equals` and `hashCode`, particularly if you are adding `Coordinate` objects to other collections.